# WebView isn't a class flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

Hi i'm following this guide from flutter: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview?hl=pt-br#3

in step 3 there is an instruction to add the flutter_webview to pubspec.yaml i add this normal without errors.
But in step 4 there is a code to replace for adding the webview widge when i add this code the line with web view get an error and the error is "The name 'WebView' isn't a class."

i add the import at the top of the main.dart "import 'package:webview_flutter_android/webview_flutter_android.dart';"
but android tells me this import is never used.

i just create a new project to see if the errors continue because maybe was a problen with the project but the error continues.

the app it's very simple has only an webview.

[dependecies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdOw9.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/978Jk.png)

i realy dont know what i'm doing wrong i follow all steps to step 4, there is an video on flutter official channel in youtube and it's works fine in the video, but i did the same steps and not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to implement a webview you actually need a controller which loads the source and manages the javascript controls etc. and a widget which renders the webpage . Here you have written the controller part but to render the webpage you need to use `WebViewWidget` ( responsible for rendering )

For better view you can wrap your WebViewWidget with `AspectRatio` to prevent overflows here's an example of whole MyApp widget

Imports

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
```

MyApp Class

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _controller = WebViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            // Update loading bar.
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {},
          onPageFinished: (String url) {},
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 9 / 16, child: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Dependencies

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  webview_flutter: ^4.2.2
```